# Bootstrap Navbar formatting not matching template

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I have two images below: one is directly from a bootstrap template, the second is with the template files (css, js, etc) copy pasted into my Rails 4 app. I tried watching the rails cast to understand the asset pipeline better http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline?view=comments but am unable to figure out what in my app is causing the template to break.

Issues I've noticed (per pictures below):
1) Navbar-brand class is underlined and not a link in my app, but is in the template.
2) the contact me section looks ugly in my site
3) the about/contact links on the upper right are not formatted in the same way as the template.

I tried to use the same files, same template, same html in my site as in the template (obviously I screwed something up).

My website is first, the original template is second. Does anyone have any immediate ideas?

[image: My website]

[image: original template]

My HTML header includes:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Comment: You need to use web inspector in your browser and some effort. No one will answer a question asked in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This post was not on the back of no effort. Spent the past 10 hours trying to understand the css files to see if I could detect anything causing this. Will try the web inspector and edit the post with more detail.

Comment: If you spent 10 hours you wasted a lot of time. Way too much. Check out application.css (in browser) and see if it contains what it should contain, I guess that is problem number one. Read about asset pipeline again and make sure all files are in place `app/assets/stylesheets/`

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.

I was able to determine that my application.css file was loading a bootstrap css file from when I installed twitter bootstrap via the rails gem, as well as the css file I used from the bootstrap template.

I fixed this issue by removing

```
=require twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap
```

from the bootstrap_and_overrides.css manifest file.